# How to restrict mouse click of check box and trigger from JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We have Table grid and having multiple columns including Select Box(CheckBox)
Now expected behaviour is on clicking on row respective CheckBox should get checked and clicking on CheckBox it should get updated.

So I implemented code -

```
$("#table_id").on("click", ".table-body-row", function(){
    $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');                                  
});
```

It is working for row but when i click on respective CheckBox it gets clicked for 2 times
  -First when a Mouse Click happens on CheckBox
  -Second when above function get called

Can anyone help here, is any other way we can handle this scenario?

Comment: Please provide table structure as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because when you click on the checkbox the `checked` state is changed. The event then continues to bubble up the DOM and is caught by your event handler on the row, which then re-sets the checked state back to its initial value so nothing appears different.

To fix this you can check that the event target was the checkbox, and if so leave the `checked` property as it is:

```js
$("#table_id").on("click", ".table-body-row", function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is(':checkbox'))
    $(':checkbox', this).prop('checked', (i, checked) => !checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
  <tr class="table-body-row">
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Foo bar</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note the explicit use of `prop()` here over triggering an event on the element. Also note that calling `stopPropagation()` on the checkbox itself won't work here as you're using a delegated event handler (therefore the event has already bubbled before being caught).

Comment: Thanks for an immediate response, your self-descriptive code and explanation. Tested and Working perfectly well.

Comment: One dependent question I missed in the description,   
Can we not use trigger event in this case? because of some processes which are on the CheckBox click.

Comment: Sure, you can trigger the event manually too. If you're having issues with that I'd suggest starting a new question

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass a click use prop to change the checkbox selection.

```
 $(':checkbox', this).prop('checked', true);
 $(':checkbox', this).prop('checked', false);
```

If it is a bubbling issue, you may need to stop the event from propagating.

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: `stopPropagation()` won't work here as it's using a delegated event handler. Therefore the event has *already* bubbled up to `#table_id` in order to be caught. Calling `stopPropagation()` at this point is too late to have any effect.